# Replace function in Java

Tags: java, replace

If i have these three different string:

```
String line = "A man walking down the road";
String word = "the road";
String sub = "the street";
```

and basically want to return this:

```
"A man walking down the street"
```

Can this be done with contains (to check if the string 'word' is included in the string 'text', and then replace to replace the text ? Because i've been trying to work this out for a while now, and i haven't got anywhere.

Comment: Yes it can be done. So what've you tried that didn't work?

Comment: i don't know what to put in the replace function @RohitJain. I've managed to use replace in other problems where i needed to add text on each end of the sentence, but in this case i don't know how i can change the text

Comment: Remember String are immutable object just by calling replace won't work you need assign the value returned from the replace call. EG: String newString = line.replace(word,sub); now your newString will have the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
String line = "A man walking down the road";
String word = "the road";
String sub = "the street";
System.out.println(line.replace(word,sub));
```